# Name Server does not change my web site IP address

Tags: domain-name-system, domain, nameserver

I'm new about the config of the web server. 
I asked my hosting company to set the DNS to point to my VALID IP address, in the university. My server is ubuntu 12.04 (desktop). I installed apache2 and bind9. Now the ns ping points to my IP (217.218.245.169), but when I ping my web site (ijnrs.com), it points to its previous IP address (5.61.27.195). I have included the db.ijnrs.com file. Would you please help me. I want www.ijnrs.com (and ijnrs.com) points to my IP address.

EDIT:
I'm aware that it takes some time for IP addresses to be propagated, however, I can now ping ns.ijnrs.com and see the desired IP addressees, while the main address is not accessible. My question was about the difference between the way these names and IP addressees propagate.

Thanks.

db.ijnrs.com

```
;
; BIND data file for local loopback interface
;
$TTL    604800
@       IN      SOA     ns.ijnrs.com. root.ijnrs.com. (
                             35         ; Serial
                         604800         ; Refresh
                          86400         ; Retry
                        2419200         ; Expire
                         604800 )       ; Negative Cache TTL
;
ijnrs.com.      IN      NS      ns.ijnrs.com.
@               IN      NS      ns.ijnrs.com.
@               IN      A       217.218.245.169
ns              IN      A       217.218.245.169
www             IN      CNAME   ijnrs.com.
```

Comment: It isn't names and IPs that propagate; it's DNS records of all types.

Comment: Would you please describe more. Do you mean my bind file is configures incorrectly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DNS changes take time to "propagate," and you may have a DNS cache on your local machine (or for the local network) that's still pointing at the old address.  I think the rule of thumb is to wait 72 hours for DNS changes to finish updating everywhere, assuming a standard DNS TTL setting (which DNS servers are free to ignore anyway).

Comment: If my config seems correct? I have seen some other such files with entries about emails, ftp, and ... . If it is necessary to put them within the file.

Comment: @remo Looks fine to me, with the exception of your TTL being (probably) longer than you may want.  Nothing you can do about that but change it and wait, though.  As to other configs with entries for ftp and email, well, those would only apply if you have a host for ftp or mail (etc).  If the only thing you have is the one website, then all you need is what you've got.

Comment: Thank you for your help. And finally, would you please introduce me a complete reference how to manage an ubuntu (web) server. a book is preferred please.

Comment: @remo Sorry - I have no idea.  Not a Ubuntu guy.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at your TTL : `$TTL    604800`

This indicates to all clients and caching nameservers how often it should check back with the authoritative nameserver for updated information. Here it is defined for 7 days.

Normally, if you plan to change your domains IP address, you should lower your TTL (24 hours) in advance, to allow the TTL change to fully propagate throughout the multiple DNS over the internet.

Also, caching nameservers will store the answer they get, and the Serial Number for the zone file. So, when you make any changes to your zone file, you should also increment the serial number.

Comment: I changed them to 86400, now. If I can check the IP of my website, tomorrow?

Comment: @remo Well, that will depend.  Any DNS server that checked, say yesterday, and got a TTL of 7 days from now won't check back for several days, and will continue to cache the old address until it does.  All you can really do it change the TTL, and wait until other DNS servers check back and get the updated record.